# extract only duplicated words from one cell strings in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to extract the only duplicated words from the text string which is located in one cell.

a text string is - dog, cat, cat, rat, horse, horse, cow, horse 
desired result - cat, horse

I found java code for it (https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-find-the-duplicate-words-in-a-string) but I need it in google sheets (script or formulas no matter) 
I tried regex functions but didn't achieve the goal.
It will be appreciated if someone can help me with this issue.

```
//java code
public class DuplicateWord {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String string = "Big black bug bit a big black dog on his big black nose";  
        int count;  

        //Converts the string into lowercase  
        string = string.toLowerCase();  

        //Split the string into words using built-in function  
        String words[] = string.split(" ");  

        System.out.println("Duplicate words in a given string : ");   
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
            count = 1;  
            for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {  
                if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {  
                    count++;  
                    //Set words[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited word  
                    words[j] = "0";  
                }  
            }  

            //Displays the duplicate word if count is greater than 1  
            if(count > 1 && words[i] != "0")  
                System.out.println(words[i]);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Result:
Duplicate words in a given string : 
big
black

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. It seems that your script is Java which is not Javascript. But in your tag, `google-apps-script` is used. Which do you want to achieve your goal using Java or Google Apps Script? 2. In your input value of `dog, cat, cat, rat, horse, horse, cow, horse desired result - cat, horse`, what is the result you want to retrieve?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike  thanks for a response. I included a link where I found this javascript. Please, forget about it, I'm looking for a google script solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function removeDupes() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const v=ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue().toLowerCase().split(/\s/);
  var s=new Set(v);
  var o=[...s].join(' ');
  Logger.log(o);
}
```

Okay this does just the opposite.

```
function removeDupes() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const v=ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue().toLowerCase().split(/\s/);
  let o=[];
  let s=new Set();
  v.forEach(function(e,i){
    if(o.indexOf(e)==-1) {
      o.push(e);
    }else{
      s.add(e);
    }
  });
  Logger.log(...s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but It works the opposite way. I need to leave duplicate values and delete unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getValue` and  [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const str = "dog, cat, cat, rat, horse, horse, cow, horse, horse";//from range.getValue()
const set = new Set(),dups = new Set();
str.split(/,\s*/).forEach(word => !(set.has(word) && dups.add(word)) && set.add(word));
console.info([...dups])
```

Comment: Hi TheMaster, thanks for a response. Is this for java or I can use it with a google script?

Comment: @user198 You can use it with Google script. Consider taking a online  JavaScript crash course. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I got an error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () , Node cannot be found in the current page.

Comment: @user Do [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-intro/#0) first. Java is NOT JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll do.